# I need to create a figure using css. I am using clip path, but cannot make perfect rounded corners. Any ideas how to do it?

Tags: css, clip-path

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGNEV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nTun.png)

How to make those figures using css? I have some progress using clip-path (clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 100% 0%, 98% 100%, 0 94%)), but corners are bad. Important to corners be rounded like on images. Idea is to use them as a background of elements.